# Grails createLink to project root?

Tags: url, grails

How can I use createLink() to create a link to the root of my Grails project?

Answer (score 29):

You can specify a `uri` of `'/'`:

```
<a href="${createLink(uri: '/')}">link text</a>
```

Comment: Right - it's relative to the running app. If you need a link that works outside of the app make it absolute: `<a href="${createLink(uri: '/', absolute: true)}">link text</a>`

Comment: Yes, in a clearer moment, I just realized that, then checked back here.  Will try it today, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

I use this code:

```
<g:link uri="/">Home</g:link>
```

Answer (score 3):

Try

```
createLink(absolute : 'true')
```

This should point to `http://localhost:8080/yourproject/` (on default set up)

Comment: That's what I would think, but it is not doing the trick.  Using both Grails 1.3.7 and 2.0.1, after creating a new app, and generating a controller called "Info", with def index = { render createLink(absolute : 'true') }, I see this: http://localhost:8080/myproject/info/index.

Comment: From your gsp, you can also use `${request.contextPath}` in a normal `<a href =/>`